# How to integrate TinyMce with Zend Framework with Gzipping and Image managers?

Tags: zend-framework, tinymce

I have done some research on this subject, and found out, that Gzipping and adding a new image manager through a plugin would not be as difficult. The only question is the Image manager.

I have seen some quite good ones, like the Image Manager for JCE, which is a Joomla wysiwyg editor, but none for TinyMce for itself.

Could someone show me a good image plugin?

P.S. SwampyFoot is out of question, as it's download links are broken, and PhP Letters Ajax image manager is quite hard to install.

Thanks!

EDIT: I just found Mad File Manager, which seems to work excelently except for a little glitch: An image can be uploaded, but cant be selected... Thats sad...

EDIT2: I've found [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/), which seems to be very promising, but I just can't get it to work properly. Somehow, the configuration is quite difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, So I have been able to answer my question myself. So here it goes:

1. Set up TinyMce with [Sozfo](http://juriansluiman.nl/en/blog/article/100/improved-tinymce-solution-for-the-zend-framework) solution. The important ting to remember here is, instead of extending your Forms from Zend_Form, you have to extend them from Sozfo_Form. As to the defining your own extendable controller, it didnt work for me, So I put the path defining helpers in my Bootstrap. And if the whole ordeal works, there is a textarea that should have TinyMCE controls, but there aren't any, try checking the comments at Sozfo, or checking if the page is cached or not. It took me a good hour, to find out, that the only reason why no JavaScript was pushed to the header was because of a *very* persistent cache.
2. Set up [KCFinder](http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/). The main problems I faced here were due to wrong paths to corresponding files. When the paths were correct, the only thing to remember is to enable it. There is a boolean to change in configuration file.
3. The last issue was adding the KCFinder to my Tinymce, and what I ended up doing was, I added the function needed to call KCFinder in TinyMCE.php View helper. ( Due to some glitch I seem to be unable to post the code here). Once you have set up your paths correctly, everything should work splendidly.

All in all, it took me about 3 days to figure this whole thing out. Talk about steep learning curve...

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [MCImageManager](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/plugins_imagemanager.php) - its not free but its an option if you're happy to pay for it

Comment: Yes, I have, but in this case paying is not an option.

Comment: no worries, just thought i'd check. I've actually built a bespoke one before. Its reasonably easy to do if you have the time.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a suggest as you've got it but swampy foot download does work

As you're already using zend framework, why not use dojo, set up the dojo form and call the editor element and integrate this  http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/_editor/plugins/LinkDialog into it?

Comment: Yes, I do know that they work, but the file type is something beyond me. Neither WinRAR or WinZip could handle the file, so I basically count the link as not working.

As to Dijit, thanks, but the main concern is the ability to manage images through the editor, and Dijit just hasn't got the options for as, as far as i can tell.